# Faceted Search with Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I'm trying to implement faceted search with Sunspot, but I must be doing something wrong.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category, :color, :condition, :item_no, :size
  searchable do
    text :color, :size
  end
end
```

This is my product model, i want to have a menu on the side of the navigation which will allow to filter results by using category, color, condition etc.

In my controller i have:

```
 def index

    @search = Product.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      facet :color
    end
    @products = @search.results

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end
```

But i keep getting an error that says:

```
Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError 
No field configured for Product with name 'color'
```

In the view I have:

```
<div id="facets">
  <h3>Category</h3>
  <ul>
    <% for row in @search.facet(:color).rows %>
      <li>
        <% if params[:color].blank? %>
          <%= link_to row.value, :color => row.value %> (<%= row.count %>)
        <% else %>
          <strong><%= row.value %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", :color => nil %>)
        <% end %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone point what to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Update:
This is a piece of the trace of the error.

```
sunspot (1.3.3) lib/sunspot/query/restriction.rb:245:in `to_solr_conditional'
sunspot (1.3.3) lib/sunspot/query/restriction.rb:92:in `to_positive_boolean_phrase'
sunspot (1.3.3) lib/sunspot/query/restriction.rb:72:in `to_boolean_phrase'
sunspot (1.3.3) lib/sunspot/query/filter.rb:11:in `to_filter_query'
sunspot (1.3.3) lib/sunspot/query/scope.rb:5:in `block in to_params'
sunspot (1.3.3) lib/sunspot/query/scope.rb:5:in `map'
sunspot (1.3.3) lib/sunspot/query/scope.rb:5:in `to_params'
sunspot (1.3.3) lib/sunspot/query/common_query.rb:51:in `block in to_params'
sunspot (1.3.3) lib/sunspot/query/common_query.rb:50:in `each'
sunspot (1.3.3) lib/sunspot/query/common_query.rb:50:in `to_params'
sunspot (1.3.3) lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb:37:in `execute'
sunspot_rails (1.3.3) lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:329:in `solr_execute_search'
sunspot_rails (1.3.3) lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:153:in `solr_search'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things missing here. First, you need to include the color as a field, and second, the facet method tells sunspot (i.e., solr) to return all the facets that are present in the result set, but not to scope the query by that facet. So, you need something like:

```
searchable do
  text :color, :size
  string :color
end


@search = Product.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
  with(:color).all_of(params[:color]) unless params[:color].blank?
  facet :color
end
```

Comment: I've added the code you suggested and amended the question with the code from the view. But now i'm getting this error. undefined method `map' for "Black":String

Comment: It just so happens I've just run into this myself - haven't worked on this in many months. I will post here when solved. If it's anything more than trivial, it probably warrants a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll post a new question.

Comment: stackoverflow likes single topic questions. the nature of your question is changing from "missing field color" to "undefined method 'map'". anyway, the problem is the all_of scope wants an array, not a string - ["Black"], not "Black". Then, the query can be scoped on multiple colors, e.g., ["Black", "Blue"]. There are any number of ways to handle this in rails, the easiest being to pass the param with an array indicator. for example, http://yourhost.com/yoururl?color[]Black&color[]Blue. In your controller, params[:color] will be an array.

Comment: thanks pduey, i've posted a new question regarding this since i realize the nature of the question changed. thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: btw, i was assuming a product could be tagged with multiple colors. if that's true, then you need to specify that in your model with ":multiple => true". And if not, then you don't need to use the any_of method, just use the equals method in your controller, which has the shorthand with(:color, params[:color])